# dynamic class or function return query result PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I used to have one function to any select query in my script, but since it's not secure I need to find out how to make a dynamic PDO class in php.

For example, I used to use this code.

```
function excute_query ($Query)
{

    if($Query_Run = mysql_query($Query))
    {
        while($DATA = mysql_fetch_array($Query_Run, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                $data_array[] = $DATA;
            }
            return $data_array;
            close();

    }
    else{
            die(mysql_error());
        }

    mysql_close();

}
```

and I can use it anywhere in my script and it return's an array with the data. in 2 lines.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$users = execute_query($sql);
```

Now I need to use the same function with PDO. I've been trying, but how I can make a class or function to do the same using PDO.

What I'm trying to say. instead of write same 4 lines to make a query, is there any way to make a function or class take a query and return the data ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty but little verbose solution would be this one

```
function execute_query( $query, $params ) {
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
$users = execute_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?',array($id));
```

but personally I hate writing the word `array`, so, I would use `func_get_args()`  and call this way

```
function execute_query() {
   global $pdo;
   $args  = func_get_args();
   $query = array_shift($args);
   $stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);
   $stmt->execute($args);
   return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
$sql   = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?';
$found = execute_query($sql,$username,$password);
```

But having a class would be apparently better.
It will let you have different functions for the different result sets, like

```
$username = db::getOne('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?',$id);
```

instead of your current

```
$user     = execute_query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?',$id);
$username = $user['name'];
```

or, even more useful ones

```
$users = db::getIndexed('id','SELECT name FROM users);
```

to get an array where keys filled with user ids or

```
$ids = db::getCol('SELECT id FROM users');
$in  = implode(",",$ids);
```

Comment: How the function will accept 3 parameters when you define the function with 2 parameters?

Comment: Oh, yeah, for the second approach you don't have to define parameters at all.

Comment: **Oh, I like it. All I have to do now is send the SQL statement with the parameters and booom!! Thank you very much.**

Comment: Except this won't work if you use `LIMIT` for example, because it requires an integer (`PDO::PARAM_INT`). Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: can I use it like this     SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT ?, ?

Comment: Looks like you cant, because the default is `PDO::PARAM_STR`, but LIMIT requires `PDO::PARAM_INT`. [Source](http://e-mats.org/2009/02/pdo-and-pdoparam_int/)

Comment: @OthmanAbahossain that's not a problem though. just make your PDO to use prepared statements by simply running `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );` code after creating a PDO instance

Comment: @OthmanAbahossain I'd be glad to see some feedback after you try the function for the the real, as I eager to know whatever issues that always come from practical usage.

Comment: @YourCommonSense How I can execute the arguments without the SQL statement ? I got this error `Invalid parameter number`.

Answer (score 1):

For your helper function to work with PDO you have a few choices:

- Pass the PDO object together with the `$query`
- Instantiate your PDO as and when you need it, using some form of factory class.

The first one could simply look like this:

```
function queryGetAll(PDO $pdo, $query)
{
    return $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

You could make it more useful by adding support for prepared statements.

```
function queryGetAll(PDO $pdo, $query, $params = array(), $style = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll($style);
}
```

To call this:

```
$results = queryGetAll($pdo, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ?", array($user_id));
```

Another wrapper you could write is `queryGetOne()`, which is like `queryGetAll()` but only returns the first result. You may also consider writing a wrapper for insert statements, returning the last inserted identifier.

**Conclusion**

All things considered, I personally don't feel these wrappers add much functionality that's not already available by just using PDO.

Btw, when using PDO, make sure you allow [exceptions to be thrown from PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php); this helps debugging your code and avoids clunky code.

Comment: Thanks, what if the query has a value ?

Comment: You mean conditions in the query? In that case it's advisable to use prepared statements; look at http://sg.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code is bad. Seriously. The `close()` function is never called since it's after the `return` statement. The `mysql_close()` is never called either for the very same reason.

That said, here is a function I'd use:

```
function execute_query( $con, $query, $statements ) {
    $q = $con->prepare( $query );
    foreach ( $statements as $statement ) {
        $q->bindParam( $statement[ 'string' ], $statement[ 'value' ], $statement[ 'type' ] );
    }
    $q->execute();
    return $q->fetchAll();
}
```

And here is a code sample using it:

```
$con = new PDO( /* ... */ );
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
$statements = array();
// Prepare a statement array
$id = array(
    'string' => ':id',
    'value' => $_GET[ 'id' ],
    'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT
);
// Add the statement to the array
$statements[] = $id;
$results = execute_query( $con, $query, $statements );
```

The verbosity from PDO comes with the prepared statements that allow a good security. Preparing the statements means you are safe with the SQL injections.

Comment: Yes, but I don't find your reasoning reasonable.

Comment: `The verbosity from PDO comes with the prepared statements that allow a good security. Preparing the statements means you are safe with the SQL injections.`

Comment: If you're not happy with SO, you don't have to remain here, you know.

Comment: I find your approach with stdclass a quite ridiculous one. Looks like you're adding verbosity just for sake of verbosity.

Comment: Well from your comments it just looks like you're there to mock people. Hopefully you've added an answer now.

Comment: I have seen a great amount of answers on SO, and my grave irony is but a conclusion I made out of them. Most of answers are impractical, both by their usage and their source: most answers are coming not from the *real experience someone had on the certain matter asked* but from just a *theory* they have in their mind - so, the solution coming right off the head, without any practical testing. While practical usage always reveal issues like one you mentioned with LIMIT clause. or a case with 10 parameters which makes the code into total mess.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I still think you shouldn't personally attack people as you have done in the comments. About the case with 10 parameters, I still prefer to explicitly set the parameters types as it's *explicit*. Adding this kind of boilerplate doesn't bother me, and doesn't bother the people maintaining my code, if it is not an unreadable mess of course, but code styling helps with this. But this is just a matter of preference/standard used. To answer this question asking for as less characters as possible, your answer is better.

Comment: With all the honesty, I didn't *attack* anyone. I cricicized your *solution*, yes, but the only matter I did attacking indeed is a stackoverflow site itself which encourage impractical answers.

Comment: When you say `(which still ugly though, as you do not know PDO)`, it is considered as personal attack. I'm not even talking about your first comment on both answers other than yours which are "impersonal personal" attacks on the people answering :-). Considering SO encouraging impractical answers, I can only agree that people just want reputation.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Your Common Sense is a troll. You're not the first person he has attacked on here. Just take a look at his account activity, or even better, the small white box positioned at the top of his profile page, stating his account status. It's good to know trolls like him get a nice suspension. xD